# Listing modules of a just created process

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, process, wmi

I'm having a bit of a problem with writing code that would list modules of all newly created process. I know why I'm not able to do so, but I'd like to know if there's some way around.

```
ManagementEventWatcher start_watch = new ManagementEventWatcher(
    new WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessStartTrace")
);
start_watch.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(watch_event);
start_watch.Start();
```

First few lines of my code use WQL and something notification-query-like to watch for newly started processes. I'm creating a new event handler to handle these creations by the `watch_event` function.

```
static void watch_event(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e) {
    Process p = Process.GetProcessById((int)(uint)e.NewEvent.Properties["ProcessID"].Value);
    newProcesses.Add(p);
}
```

The `watch_event` function itself is pretty simple, only a line that gets a `Process` object based on the ID of process just created.

I thought myself this should be working, so I set a breakpoint at the other line and started debugging, but it didn't work as I expected.

It says there's no such process´, although WMI just notified me that there is - it was just created. 
For the record, I also tried to list all process by `Process.GetProcesses()` and I found out that everytime my event handler is called, there's one process marked as `Idle` at the end of returned collection. I can't retrieve its ID or name, because it throws `Win32Exception`.

So here's my question: am I doing something wrong? Should I be gathering information about newly created processes in some other way, or is there a function in API I don't know about that makes this possible?

Thank you.

Comment: I did notice trouble when tinkering with this a while ago.  Dismissed it as a race condition, pretty hard to diagnose since the Process class uses a "forbidden" internal ntdll function under the hood.  Consider continuing to use WMI to obtain info about the process, Win32_Process class.

Comment: Thank you. Does the `Win32_Process` class contain fields I could use for module retrieval (to be more specific, I need a list of DLLs and executables used by the process)?

Comment: Ask the almighty google first.  CIM_ProcessExecutable.